# ngGrid build-in search box is not working for me in 2.0.8 version

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I did try use build in search box in ngGrid and it is not working for me in version 2.0.8.

When i step back to 2.0.7. it`s working. Do  i need to change something in code to use it in 2.0.8?

jquery    v. 2.0.3
angularjs v. 1.2.15
ngGrid    v. 2.0.8

Comment: why do you need to use the latest version?

Comment: I don`t need it Alex, just learning things and because i didn`t work w/Angular before, i have started with the latest versions.

Comment: Here's a plunker demonstrating the issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/9piZ4yyGB38mwvlXsbPo?p=preview  I will try to track down the issue on Monday.

Comment: @Denis this should be fixed in 2.0.11.